# Prometheus: several exporters with push-proxy

Tags: prometheus

I want to send metrics to a Prometheus instance where the client is behind a firewall. So I am using [push-proxy](https://github.com/prometheus-community/PushProx) on the client (`--metrics-addr=":9101"`, `--proxy-url=http://xxx:8082`) and the machine running Prometheus (port 8082, `--web.listen-address=":8082"`). On the client there is also the `prometheus-node-exporter` installed (running on it's default port 9100).

In `prometheus.yaml`on the server I do:

```
  - job_name: push_proxy
    proxy_url: http://localhost:8082/
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['hostname_of_client:9101']
```

That is all based on the manual / documentation and I Prometheus I can see the push proxy client status. But how to tell the push-proxy client to grep the information from the node exporter? With `--metrics-addr=":9100"` I got `address already in use` error. And most important: How to use a second exporter (like [nftables_exporter](https://github.com/Intrinsec/nftables_exporter)) on the client? Can `--metrics-addr` be some kind of list? `--metrics-addr=":9101,:9102"` results in `too many colons in address`.

Comment: Maybe try https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/prometheus

Comment: My understanding of pushrox is that you need only one instance of pushprox-client on every client machine. And then it automatically asks ports configured in the prometheus' target list for its fqdn.

Comment: Also, iiuc, you should pass `--metrics-addr=":9101"`. It doesn't do what you want it to.